# iPhone Keyboard key value return

Tags: iphone, keyboard, events

I would like to know if a method like touchesBegan for touches Event exists for the iPhone keyboard. I mean just how to know when I press a key, which value is it. (Don't display it on UITextfield or UILabel but display it with an NSLog for example).
Is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `UITextFieldDelegate Protocol` method:

`– textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`

The keyboard sends this every time a key is pressed so you can decide if you want to display the character associated with the key or perform some other action.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the keyboard view direct is strictly undocumented, so don't think of applying it to any AppStore apps.

However, you can make an off-screen text field, and use it to capture keyboard input.

Comment: Yes I know and I applied your solution ;)